# Mock angular service data response

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have an Api service which is in charge of controlling all my http requests. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE...

I'm trying to write some unitTests and I get a problem with the following scenario.

```
self.Api.post('/myEndpoint/action/', actionData)
    .then(function(resp){
      result = _.get(resp, 'data.MessageList');
      if(resp.status = 200 && result) {
        setActionResults(resp.data);
      }
    });
```

I want to mock in my unitTest the resp. What should I do? Must I mock the httpBackend service as here http://plnkr.co/edit/eXycLiNmlVKjaZXf0kCH?p=preview ? Can I do it in other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `httpBackend` is the way to go, mocking each request made by your application will work just fine. However you can mock your entire service as well, and unit test using the mocked service instead of the original. Regardless, `httpBackend` is much more simple to handle that (for http request services) than creating a new service with the same interface of the original. But in some case, you may need to control what your services are doing, therefore you will have to use service mocking.

For example:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('DataService', function ($http) {
        this.getData = function () {
            return $http.get('http://my.end.point/api/v1/data')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                     });
        };
    });

angular.module('myAppMock')    
    .service('MockedDataService', function ($q) {
        this.getData = function () {
            return $q.resolve({ data: 'myData' }); // you can add a delay if you like
        }
    });
```

Comment: that mockedDataService is what I'm looking for... Can I define it inside my tests? or where you suggest to define it?

Comment: Well, you can define it wherever you want. Mostly, it's defined in a separated module used only for this and then it's appended from the `beforeEach` loop to override an especific dependency.